# Skybox sun shows black cube

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I added a plane and gave it a Skybox/Procedural shader, the problem is the sun is showing a black cube, and I don't know why:

[image]

I just chose it and did nothing more, is my unity editor corrupted?

Comment: Did you find a working solution to this?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, your information was very useful. I ended up using a normal sky box on a 2D game, it is fine. The only problem is that the sun is deformed because perspective but it looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skybox shaders don't calculate things properly applied to a plane's material, because its meant to output colors on a box surrounding the camera.

If you want to use the skybox shader, here is what the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Skybox.html) says:

> To implement a Skybox create a skybox material. Then add it to the scene by using the **Window > Rendering
> Lighting Settings** menu item and specifying your skybox material as the Skybox on the Scene tab.
>
> Adding the Skybox Component
> to a Camera is useful if you want to override the default Skybox. E.g. You might have a split screen game using two Cameras, and want the Second camera to use a different Skybox. To add a Skybox Component to a Camera, click to highlight the Camera and go to **Component->Rendering->Skybox**.